# Isabelle cardinality

Tags: set, isabelle, cardinality

I have a relatively simple question, its causing me some problems in isabelle.

Im trying to prove the following:

```
∃ b . inv_Board b
```

The board is a set. The invariant on board is:

```
card b <= FINISHED
```

Where finished is an int value of 24. I'm using my own types though so its actually a VDMNat type and I have to cast it like so:

```
int (card b) <= FINISHED
```

Sledgehammer isn't working, I have 1 subgoal:

```
∃b. int (card b) ≤ FINISHED
```

any ideas?

Comment: Is `b` a concrete value in that context for which you know the invariant holds? What happens if you do `apply (rule exI[of _ b])`?

Comment: What's the type of `b`?
Does the proof work if formulate the invariant without your special typing, i.e. with `card b <= 24`?

Answer (score 0):

If »FINISHED« is an int value of 24, then there should be an equational theorem `‹FINISHED = 24›`.

Then you can proceed roughly like

```
have "int (card {}) ≤ FINISHED"
  by (simp add: ‹FINISHED = 24›)
then show "∃b. int (card b) ≤ FINISHED"
  ..
```